# Clear entire row if no content/text/number found in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA script that will delete (clear content) of the entire row if one of the cells within the rows is found to be blank or does not have any text or integer value.

I'm almost there, but I think my code is stuck in the for loop. Please let me know how I can further improve my code.

```
    Sub Remove_Rows_BlankData()
          For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count  'SHEET LEVEL

        Sheets(SheetCount).Visible = True
        Sheets(SheetCount).Select
        StartRow = 2
        ' EndRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 34)
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))         
        'REMOVE ROWS W/ ANY BLANK CELLS

        Dim DRow As Variant  ' Sets DRow = Row w/ Blank
            'From start row to last row

        Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.ClearContents


         Next

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your sub to avoid having to `Select` a worksheet in order to use it. By referencing each worksheet in the loop using a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), the cells and properties of each worksheet can be dealt with without resorting to selecting¹ the worksheet just to use the inherent association of the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
Sub Remove_Rows_BlankData()
    Dim ws As Long, fr As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long

    On Error Resume Next   'just in case there are no blank cells

    For ws = 5 To Worksheets.Count  'SHEET LEVEL
        With Worksheets(ws)

            .Visible = True
            'Sheets(SheetCount).Select  'not necessary to select in order to process
            fr = 2
            ' EndRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 34)
            lr = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            lc = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

            With .Range(.Cells(fr, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.ClearContents
            End With

        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Note that no variables are created (aka `Dim`) within the loop; only reassigned values.

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question, but the solution is not the best.

The problem of deleting columns or rows, if any of the cells is empty or with a certain value, **cannot be done** with the function:

```
For Each myCell In Selection
    If myCell.Value = "" Then Rows(myCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

since the deletion of a row displaces all the other rows, losing the reference. If, for example, we have rows 1 and 2 without data and row 3 with data, this code will delete only row 1 and we will have to run the function again to delete the other row, which is now in position 1. It will continue to fail as long as there are empty spaces in contiguous rows and will hang when it reaches the end of the list and all are empty cells.

The problem is that **Selection** works on the range of cells that are selected within the box that we have made with the mouse or individually and does not update when we delete a row. Since the **For Each** loop does not take this offset into account, the adjacent row that should also be deleted will no longer be deleted. In other words, if we delete row 1, row 2 becomes row 1. The thing gets more complicated if we put more examples, so I will go straight to the solution.

This is my code and it works perfectly on any selected range.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyColumns ()
Dim MySelection As Range
Set MySelection = Selection

On Error GoTo error_
redo_:
MySelection.Select
For Each myCell In MySelection
        If myCell.Value = "" Then   'or .Value="xxx" 
            Rows(myCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            GoTo redo_
        End If
Next
    
error_:
End Sub
```

The lines:

```
3-  Set MySelection = Selection
11- GoTo redo_
```

are the key of the function.

**MySelection** is going to store the initial range, but, and here's the beauty, as we delete rows, columns or individual cells, **MySelection** will update itself. After **EntireRow.Delete** we have **GoTo redo_**. This line is also important since it is in charge of performing the **For Each** loop again but with **MySelection** updated.

The **MySelection.Select** line is only there to visualize how the range is adapting to each row deletion and can be removed from the code without any problem.

The line:

```
On Error GoTo error_
```

is to avoid the error if **MySelection** ends up empty.

NaClU2